# Building a custom word similarity

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, gensim

Am working with similarity matches using spacy. But as per my needs in the project, I am trying to build a custom word similarity. I was going through the internet to get leads, but dint find any.
Is there a way to actually build this ?

```
My thoughts : {"Account": ["acct", "account no", "acount no", "actno", "act no", "acct no"]}
```

For example, if I want the word account which is represented as the list given above, it should match and give me the list of words present in a text.

```
Output : Text = "This a custom word similarity builder. The acct no for this can be STACKCODE. The only account no will be found in the stackoverflow"
```

When I train it with all my inputs, and use word similarity, it should output me the words found.

```
Output : ["acct no", "account no"]
```

Comment: I think the term that you are looking for is not "word similarity", but a "synset", i.e. a synonym ring. Depending on the use case, many existing retrieval frameworks already support this as a form of query expansion, i.e. Apache Solr.

Comment: Please consult [ask] and [reprex]